# Using pygame on a mac?

Tags: python, macos, netbeans, pygame

I was trying to get pygame on my mac to work. I got it running in terminal. But I run into issues when trying to use it with netbeans or trying to run the file. It gives me the error

```
from pygame.locals import *
   ImportError: No module named locals
```

any help? Thanks!

Comment: Did you get any warnings or errors when installing pygame?

Comment: Nope, and it runs perfectly fine in terminal

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python installed?  Perhaps the default Mac installation, and one from python.org or port...  It could be using the wrong version of python

Comment: does this import work in an interactive python shell?

Comment: I think I do have multiple versions of python installed, How would I change it to use the right version? and sorry what exactly do you mean by interactive python shell?

Comment: @bipolar [this](http://superuser.com/questions/35256/how-can-i-change-the-default-python-version-on-snow-leopard) might help with your versions. An interactive session is started when you type `python` at the command line, and get `>>` back, waiting for your input. Try typing `import pygame` from there.

Comment: Ok sorry for the late response, but Pygames works perfectly in the interactive shell and it also looks like its now working while running a file but stil fails while using Netbeans.

Comment: hm decided just to not use Netbeans, works fine in textwrangler

Comment: You can do `import sys; print sys.executable; print sys.version` to see what Python executables/versions you're running in the netbeans and textwrangler environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want to use netbeans, I think you should take a look at [ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython)

Activepython basically lets you install different pythons on your machine and be able to select between them (there's a lot more features I'm sure).

My advice would be to go to the console and type

```
>python 
>>> from pygame.locals import *
```

If that works, ctrl-c out and do a python -v to find out the version.

Once you have the version, you can use activepython to select that version by running:
sudo pysel [version]. For instance for python2.7:
sudo pysel 2.7

This should switch the python over and your netbeans should (hopefully) work with it.